# I'm using Point(x,y) on a picturebox to obtain the pixel's color. but what comes back bears no relationship to what x and y point to

Tags: vb6, point

I'm matching up wood pictures to a solid color. It should be simple to examine a 50x50 portion of the picture and develop the average red, green, and blue equivalent. But `point(x,y)` appears to return a constant that doesn't match. The steps are:

```vb
picimage.Picture = LoadPicture(filename)
StretchBlt woodpic.hdc, 0, 0, woodpic.ScaleWidth, woodpic.ScaleHeight, _
           picimage.hdc, 0, 0, picimage.ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight, vbSRCCOPY

woodpic.Refresh

For X = 1 To 50
    For Y = 1 To 50
        value = woodpic.Point(X, Y)
        DisectColor value, Redv, Greenv, Bluev
    Next Y
Next X
```

My version of alder color is 9812440 but `Point` returns nothing but 15790320.

Comment: Why are you using StretchBlt instead of properly loading the picture into the picturebox? 15790320, being &HF0F0F0, is the gray window background of an empty picturebox.

Comment: Is the picturebox visible so you can see visually if the contents it has are what you expect?

Comment: stretchbit use just to improve user experiance. that i get/see only gray cofirms stretchblt doen't work for .jpg.

Comment: stretchbit use just to improve user experiance. that i get/see only gray cofirms stretchblt doen't work for .jpg. on to next problem, skipping the stretchblt. Poin(x,y) dosn't point to the x,y specified. I see this by changing pixel color to red after sampling. The patch is 70x114 pixels, so my loop from 1,1 to 50,50 should always point to a pixel within the patch. It doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

When all is said and done, only .bmp files can be so interrogated. So, the final  solution is:

```
 woodpic.Picture = LoadPicture(filename)
  For X = 1 To 25 ' the sample  must be at least this big
      For Y = 1 To 25
          SampleValue = woodpic.Point(X, Y) 'get sample
          Sample = triad(SampleValue)
          woodpic.PSet (X, Y), 255 'paint to leave evidence behind
          cnt = cnt + 1
          averagecolor = average(Sample) 'recompute average
          UpdateScreen
      Next Y
  Next X
```